Backlight turns off or screen turns black when the brightness is 100% and can't turn off auto adjust brightness by sensor
I have two problems.
Problem 1
Can't turn off auto adjust brightness by sensor. I can't see option in setting. I tried with dconf but it doesn't work.
Problem 2
When I put the brightness at 100%, the backlight is off (the screen is black), but the computer is still running. If I want to turn it back on, I have to reduce the brightness a little bit. I use function keys to reduce the brightness back. I can control the brightness from both UI and function keys. The problem is just the screen turns black (backlight turns off) when the brightness is 100%.
My laptop is an HP Elitebook 8460p. OS is Ubuntu 22.04.
What i tried:
I tried to solve with dconf software to fix both problems, but it didn't work.
I tried to change these lines in grub config (/etc/default/grub)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"  

Here is the result:

I tried with this command
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled 'false'  

When did the problems start?
I recently changed my battery. Before I used my laptop by plugging it in. Today I changed to a new battery that has a little bit different power.
